# Conditional URL rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to setup an htaccess redirect for the following situation.

If an app hits a URL containing `/cms` as the first segment `http://originaldomain.com/cms` I want to redirect to a secure domain `https://differentdomain.com/cms`.

If a URL hits `https://differentdomain.com` on any URL other then act, URL, system, or is a not a post then I want to redirect the user to `http://originaldomain.com/requestedurl`.

act is OK:

```
https://differentdomain.com/act?fiudsbsdfn=sfds
```

URL is OK:

```
https://differentdomain.com/url
```

system is OK:

```
https://differentdomain.com/system
```

POST methods are OK to any domain just redirect GET methods

Is this possible within an htaccess file?

Comment: `then act, url, system, or is a not a post` can you explain better this part if possible with examples of URLs.

Comment: Did that worked for u ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both domains are on the same root folder and host:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^originaldomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://differentdomain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

If they are not on the same root and folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://differentdomain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Now the 2nd part if the url is not a act, url, system or post:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(act\?(.*)|url|system)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://originaldomain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Basically this should work, if it does after you test change to 302 to 301 if needed.